Which DE is closest to MacOS's?
I was just wondering in people's opinion which desktop environment is closest to that of MacOS's. I'm a huge fan of their DE but I want a pre-packaged one for Ubuntu that gets me as close as possible to MacOS without me having to do everything by hand. It doesn't need to look exactly like MacOS, but I want one that has a glossy look and the dock at the bottom.

Elementary OS is heavily inspired by Mac.
But you can tweak every GNOME distribution to look like MacOS. You just have to install a theme

Of course there is no DE which exactly resembles MacOS.
However, with custom themes KDE, you can customize and get something close.
Check out the McMojave-KDE theme or MacSequoia-KDE themeby vinceliuice. You have to set it up with KVantum to get transcluency.
For icon theme, you can use WhiteSur Icon theme or La Capitaine Icon  heme.
End results:

